# TLS1.3 OpenSSL tls alert unrecognized_name do not appear

Tags: openssl, tls1.2, tls1.3

trying to provoke a TLS alert unrecognized_name for TLS1.3 using OpenSSL but it doesn't appear.
For TLS1.2 it works. Does anyone understand why? Here are examples of commands:

```
openssl s_server -accept 9443 -key signed-pem.key -cert signed-pem.cert -tls1_2 -key2 anydesk.com.key -cert2 anydesk.com.cert -servername anydesk.com -cipher ALL:COMPLEMENTOFALL
Setting secondary ctx parameters
Using default temp DH parameters
ACCEPT

openssl s_client -connect 10.10.10.55:9443  -CAfile signed-pem.cert -tls1_2  -cipher DHE-RSA
-AES128-SHA -state -servername desk.com
CONNECTED(00000005)
SSL_connect:before SSL initialization
SSL_connect:SSLv3/TLS write client hello
SSL3 alert read:warning:unrecognized name
SSL_connect:SSLv3/TLS write client hello
SSL_connect:SSLv3/TLS read server hello
```

And for TLS1.3:

```
openssl s_server -accept 9443 -key signed-pem.key -cert signed-pem.cert -tls1_3 -key2 anydesk.com.key -cert2 anydesk.com.cert -servername anydesk.com -cipher ALL:COMPLEMENTOFALL
Setting secondary ctx parameters
Using default temp DH parameters
ACCEPT

openssl s_client -connect 10.10.10.55:9443  -CAfile signed-pem.cert -tls1_3  -ciphersuites TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 -state -servername desk.com
CONNECTED(00000005)
SSL_connect:before SSL initialization
SSL_connect:SSLv3/TLS write client hello
SSL_connect:SSLv3/TLS write client hello
SSL_connect:SSLv3/TLS read server hello
SSL_connect:TLSv1.3 read encrypted extensions
SSL_connect:SSLv3/TLS read server certificate
SSL_connect:TLSv1.3 read server certificate verify
SSL_connect:SSLv3/TLS read finished
SSL_connect:SSLv3/TLS write change cipher spec
SSL_connect:SSLv3/TLS write finished
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's due to this code in OpenSSL:

https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/a65c8d8f737fe4e67d0b37e2b20dc1adccd93112/ssl/statem/extensions.c#L994-L997

```
    case SSL_TLSEXT_ERR_ALERT_WARNING:
        /* TLSv1.3 doesn't have warning alerts so we suppress this */
        if (!SSL_IS_TLS13(s))
            ssl3_send_alert(s, SSL3_AL_WARNING, altmp);
```

You will note in your TLSv1.2 output you see that the alert is a warning:

```
SSL3 alert read:warning:unrecognized name
```

TLSv1.3 does not use the "severity" indication within an alert. All error alerts are considered fatal. Therefore OpenSSL does not send this alert because it is not fatal in the context.